# My other hard drives are invisible, but still accessible

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, windows-explorer

[image: A screenshot showing the drive visible in one window, but not in the other.]
For some reason I cannot see any of my other hard drives through Windows 8's explorer window. I can see them in disk management, and opening them from there works. They are also visible in file-related dialogs.

How can I fix this? I have already tried restarting the `explorer` process.

Answer (score 0):

Show them all out like this:
Start=> Run=>Enter “control folders” in the blank and click “Ok”=>Choose “View” on the appearing “Folder Options” interface=> Select “show hidden files and folders”.